# github graphql api, what does "clientMutationId" mean?

Tags: graphql, github-api, relay, github-graphql, graphql-relay

I saw `clientMutationId` field in [example-strong-typing](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/migrating-from-rest/#example-strong-typing) documentation.

```js
mutation {
  addComment(input:{clientMutationId: 1234, subjectId: "MDA6SXNzdWUyMjcyMDA2MTT=", body: "Looks good to me!"}) {
    clientMutationId
    commentEdge {
      node {
        body
        repository {
          id
          name
          nameWithOwner
        }
        issue {
          number
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what does `clientMutationId` mean?  How can I generate it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`clientMutationId` is not directly related with GraphQL but it is with [graphql-relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html).

Check [Understanding Relay Mutations](https://github.com/chrisbolin/understanding-relay-mutations) for a better explanation.

> *clientMutationId. This ID is generated by the Relay client behind the scenes to track the mutation's progress.*

Comment: Also note, it's optional. Personally wasn't sure if it was required at first.