# graphql clientMutationId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, relay

I'm practicing with GraphQL and testing out some mutations on Altair. All the mutations require an extra input called `clientMutationId`. According to a link on this post [github graphql api, what does "clientMutationId" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303530/github-graphql-api-what-does-clientmutationid-mean) the ID is generated, but I don't know how to find out what my `clientMutationId` is, or if i'm even understanding it right.

Comment: Is `clientMutationId` actually required? For Github for instance it is optional.

Comment: i'm not sure is there a way to check if an input is optional on altair?

Comment: If the type has an exclamation point after it, it is required, otherwise it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `clientMutationId` in the recent relay.  Have a look at Sibelius' workshop: https://github.com/sibelius/relay-workshop.

Or an updated step-by-step guide for the newly created documentation on Relay v11: https://relay.dev/docs/getting-started/step-by-step-guide/